# creating a matrix from from a list of subjects with different genes present or absent with python

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, crosstab

I have a file with different subjects that have a list of genes that are present per subject (new line per gene). I would like to restructure the data to a matrix with the different subjects in the rows and then a column for every gene that is present (with a 1 or 0 for present or absent). I have the original data as an excel file that I have imported with pandas to try and do this with Python. But honestly I have no clue how to do this in a nice way.

[image of how the data is structured and of how it is supposed to be formatted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixG2G.png)

I really appreciate all the help I can get!

So many thanks already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your file original file:

```
Subject,Gene
subject1,gene1
subject1,gene2
subject1,gene3
subject2,gene1
subject2,gene4
subject3,gene2
subject3,gene4
subject3,gene5
```

Then you can do something like this with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("genes.csv")
>>> pd.crosstab(df["Subject"], df["Gene"])
Gene      gene1  gene2  gene3  gene4  gene5
Subject                                    
subject1      1      1      1      0      0
subject2      1      0      0      1      0
subject3      0      1      0      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot()`

```
df['count'] = 1
df.pivot(index='Subject', columns='Gene', values='count')

Gene       gene1    gene2   gene3   gene4   gene5
Subject                 
subject1    1.0      1.0    1.0      NaN    NaN
subject2    1.0      NaN    NaN      1.0    NaN
subject3    NaN      1.0    NaN      1.0    1.0
```

## UPDATED -- Full example based your comment

```
# import pandas module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read your excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r'path\to\your\file\myFile.xlsx')

# create a new column call 'count' and set it to a value of 1
df['count'] = 1

# use pivot and assign it to a new variable: df2
df2 = df.pivot(index='Subject', columns='Gene', values='count').replace(np.nan, 0)

# print your new dataframe
print(df2)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the respons. I haven't quite got it to work. If I use script with: 'import pandas as pd' then 'df = pd.read_excel("path+file")' and then I am not sure how to define the variable with the "count" in it. And can I give the df.pivot a name like: 'name = df.pivot( index='Subject', columns='Gene', values='count')' and print it with: 'print name' at the end?

Comment: @newbie_here i updated my answer to show you a full example

Comment: Thanks Chris. I get it now. Also a very nice approach! thanks a lot!